# Writing PCI driver for DMA transfer on Qemu

Tags: linux-device-driver, qemu, dma, pci

I am writing a PCI device on Qemu and driver(LKM) in the guest OS. While Qemu provides an example PCI device, **edu**([edu.txt](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/specs/edu.txt) and [edu.c](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/misc/edu.c)) with it's distribution, I am having trouble writing the kernel module to do DMA transfer. A basic driver has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315265/how-to-add-a-new-device-in-qemu-source-code) but it does not support DMA.

I am following the implementation of the link and [this](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/master/kernel_module/pci.c). I tried to transmit buffer to the PCI device from the IRQ handler. The device can read the data (**pci_dma_read**) but the I am not getting the correct data that I am supposed to receive. Here is the code segment that is doing DMA transfer:

```
static int write_to_HyPerf(void *dev, void* addr, uint32_t size)
{
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    * PCI address 'addr':
    * addr     -> DMA source address
    * 0x40000  -> DMA destination address
    * 100      -> DMA transfer count
    * 1        -> DMA command register
    * while (DMA command register & 1)
    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    iowrite32((u32 *)dma_handle_to_device, mmio + IO_DMA_SRC);
    iowrite32(DMA_START, mmio + IO_DMA_DST);
    iowrite32((u32 *)size, mmio + IO_DMA_XCNT);
    iowrite32(DMA_CMD | DMA_IRQ, mmio + IO_DMA_CMD);
}
```

I also have setup coherent mapping using ***dma_alloc_coherent***.

```
vaddr_to_device = dma_alloc_coherent(&(dev->dev), DMA_SIZE, &dma_handle_to_device, GFP_ATOMIC);
```

The complete code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/proywm/15b38a293770b0aaa99eaf1f03a2c9f7). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you having problem in your driver.

In this case you can use this:
https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/master/kernel_modules/qemu_edu.c

and you can use dd command as in this script to write and read from your device:
https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/master/rootfs_overlay/lkmc/qemu_edu.sh

Then all you need is to write the wanted dma values to the correct address
like in the edu.c code:

```c
    case 0x80:
        dma_rw(edu, false, &val, &edu->dma.src, false);
        break;
    case 0x88:
        dma_rw(edu, false, &val, &edu->dma.dst, false);
        break;
    case 0x90:
        dma_rw(edu, false, &val, &edu->dma.cnt, false);
        break;
    case 0x98:
        dma_rw(edu, false, &val, &edu->dma.cmd, false);
        break;
```

Comment: When I tried to write to ```edu->dma.src``` at address 0x80 and then read such value. The value I got was not expected. According to the source code of edu device, it seems that reading from/writing to address 0x80 should be the same as that of address 0x08, which is the factorial field. However, for address 0x08 (fact), it works well; but for address 0x80, it did not work as expected. May I know if you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure ...
did you checked your endian is correct?
(could be causing 0x80->0x08)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made a "silly" mistake by writing to address 80 instead of 0x80. That is why for address 0x08 it works since 0x08 is equal to 8 in decimal, while for address 0x80 it does not work.