# Support several edu devices in QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, qemu

I am studying kernel writing by using the edu device in the QEMU. I saw how to add a new device and saw the kernel [how to add new device in qemu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315265/how-to-add-a-new-device-in-qemu-source-code). Now I want to add several device instances by running -device edu several time when running qemu (qemu-system-x86_64 ... -device edu -device edu -device edu ...). Now, when running the kernel above, I get the command line in endless loop. I wondering , how should the kernel be writing in order to support several instances ?