# any known issue with ioread64() / iowrite64() on a PCIe bus?

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, pci-e, nxp-microcontroller, memory-mapped-io

I have a similar issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901446/how-to-use-ioread64-and-iowrite64-for-accessing-io-memory) but with a different behavior.

We have an FPGA (from Altera) acts as a 32KB memory on a PCIe bus of IMX8M-Plus CPU (ARM Cortex-A53).

I wrote a simple driver to access FPGA's memory. As you can see from `lspci` output below, 32KB memory mapped to Region 4 (BAR4) and I use `avalon_ioctl_set_operation()` and `avalon_ioctl_get_operation()` to get and set BAR content.

```c
static int avalon_ioctl_get_operation(unsigned long arg, uint8_t op_size)
{
    struct avalon_pcie_operation o;

    if (copy_from_user(&o, (void __user*)arg, sizeof(o)))
        return -EFAULT;         
            
    if (o.bar >= PCI_SRIOV_NUM_BARS)
        return -EFAULT;

    if (!io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar])
        return -ENOMEM;
            
    if (!IS_ALIGNED(o.offset, op_size))
        return -EFAULT;

    switch (op_size)
    {
        case 1:
            o.data8 = ioread8(io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 2:
            o.data16 = ioread16(io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 4:
            o.data32 = ioread32(io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 8:
            o.data64 = ioread64(io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        default:
            return -EFAULT;
    }   
            
    if (copy_to_user((void __user *)arg, &o, sizeof(o)))
        return -EFAULT;
            
    return 0;
}

static int avalon_ioctl_set_operation(unsigned long arg, uint8_t op_size)
{
    struct avalon_pcie_operation o;

    if (copy_from_user(&o, (void __user*)arg, sizeof(o)))
        return -EFAULT; 
        
    if (o.bar >= PCI_SRIOV_NUM_BARS)
        return -EFAULT;

    if (!io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar])
        return -ENOMEM;
            
    if (!IS_ALIGNED(o.offset, op_size))
        return -EFAULT;

    switch (op_size)
    {
        case 1:
            iowrite8(o.data8, io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 2:
            iowrite16(o.data16, io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 4:
            iowrite32(o.data32, io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        case 8:
            iowrite64(o.data64, io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] + o.offset);
            break;
        default:
            return -EFAULT;
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

For my testing, I used BAR4 and offset 0. Whenever I call those functions for 8/16/32 bit variants of read/write all are working fine. I can read whatever I write.

But when I attempt to use `iowrite64()` and `ioread64()` from offset 0, I read garbage data (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) and PCIe config page is altered and PCIe device stops functioning (you can see `lspci` output in the altered state at the bottom). And that is happening immediately after `ioread64()` function call.

I stepped into `ioread64()` function and saw that at the end it uses `__raw_readq()` which is defined as

```c
static inline u64 __raw_readq(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    u64 val;
    asm volatile(ALTERNATIVE("ldr %0, [%1]",
                 "ldar %0, [%1]",
                 ARM64_WORKAROUND_DEVICE_LOAD_ACQUIRE)
             : "=r" (val) : "r" (addr));
    return val;
}
```

We use Linux v5.4 aarch64, I believe that accessing to a bus as a 64-bit should be fine.

```sh
uname -a
Linux 5.4.193-0+git.a301219f58a2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 15 14:09:11 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the `lspci -vv` output at the beginning of the test:

```auto
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 / PCIe bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 218
        Region 0: Memory at 18000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=ff, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
        Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 18100000-181fffff [size=1M]
        Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
        Expansion ROM at 18200000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=64K]
        BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
                Address: bc022000  Data: 0000
                Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
                        ExtTag- RBE+
                DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt+
                RootCap: CRSVisible+
                RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna+ CRSVisible+
                RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP+, LTR-
                         10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-, LN System CLS Not Supported, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-, ARIFwd-
                         AtomicOpsCap: Routing- 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled ARIFwd-
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn- EgressBlck-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
                         EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
                RootCmd: CERptEn+ NFERptEn+ FERptEn+
                RootSta: CERcvd+ MultCERcvd+ UERcvd- MultUERcvd-
                         FirstFatal- NonFatalMsg- FatalMsg- IntMsg 0
                ErrorSrc: ERR_COR: 0000 ERR_FATAL/NONFATAL: 0000
        Capabilities: [148 v1] Secondary PCI Express
                LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn-, PerformEqu-
                LaneErrStat: 0
        Capabilities: [158 v1] L1 PM Substates
                L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
                          PortCommonModeRestoreTime=10us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
                L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1- ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1-
                           T_CommonMode=10us
                L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=10us
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 RAM memory: Altera Corporation Device e001
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 219
        Region 0: Memory at 18108000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512]
        Region 4: Memory at 18100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000bc022000  Data: 0001
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 8GT/s, Width x2, ASPM not supported
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s (ok), Width x1 (downgraded)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
                         10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+, EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
                         EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [200 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1172 Rev=0 Len=044 <?>
        Capabilities: [300 v1] Secondary PCI Express
                LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn-, PerformEqu-
                LaneErrStat: 0
        Kernel driver in use: avalon-dma
        Kernel modules: avalon_drv
```

Corrupted state after `ioread64()`:

```auto
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 / PCIe bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 218
        Memory at 18000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=ff, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
        Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 18100000-181fffff [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at 18200000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Secondary PCI Express
        Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 RAM memory: Altera Corporation Device e001 (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Kernel driver in use: avalon-dma
        Kernel modules: avalon_drv
```

Do you know any restrictions available not to access PCIe bus as 64-bit on a 64-bit CPU with 64-bit OS? Or is there any special procedure that I need to follow to use `ioread64()`?

Explanation for @0andriy comment: I went through iMX8M-Plus reference manual and it says that it supports 32- and 64-bit PCI Express addresses and also 64 bit MSI at hardware level but I'm not sure if it is supported at Linux driver level. Do you know how I can be sure about it? About your question, The reason why I did choose to use ioreadXX/iowriteXX apis at the first place is that I have an example avalon dma driver and the driver accesses to the DMA registers in the FPGA which are mapped to BAR0 by using ioread32/iowrite32 apis. DMA and all MSI interrupts are working fine. Basically I followed the same approach. Only exception which is not used by the Avalon dma driver but in my custom driver was using ioread64/iowrite64 apis which I had problems there and trying to figure it out why.

Comment: What's the value of `io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar]`? And more generic question, why do you use `ioreadXX()`/`iowriteXX()` instead of corresponding `readX()`/`writeX()`?

Comment: @0andriy it is the output of `io_dev.bar_addrs[o.bar] = pci_ioremap_bar(pci_dev, bar);` ioreadXX/iowriteXX versions call __raw_write or read/b/w/l/q at the end. They are all same.

Comment: So, have you read the documentation to your PCI Root Complex? Does it allow 64-bit MMIO transactions at all? Because it all sounds like an integration HW bug (or feature if it's documented).

Comment: Also the second Q in my first comment left unanswered (I was not asking about implementation details, I was asking _why_ you chose those APIs in the first place).

Comment: @0andriy my comment was long, so I placed mine into the bottom of the question

Comment: Thank you. I am lack of any new ideas and if I was you, I would ask the HW vendor for support at this stage.